# Mouse cursor becomes invisible in certain applications

Tags: mouse, arch-linux, gnome3

Since this morning the input configuration of my system is going haywire. The most annoying thing is that when using certain applications like the Evolution email client, the cursor becomes invisible.
The same happens in the Gnome Tweak Tool, but other applications - like Chrome, my terminal emulator or development IDE - work just great.

I'm not aware of having installed any updates yesterday or making any reconfiguration and thus am stumped by what may be the problem.

I already tried changing the cursor configuration in my `~/.Xresources` and while that changes the cursor, it still becomes invisible in those applications.

Another thing that doesn't work anymore - even though aforementioned Gnome Tweak Tool says that it's still configured like that - is temporarily switching of keyboard layouts while the caps key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few seconds after posting I had an epiphany and went back to the login screen. It seem like there has been a change in some package and now the "GNOME" session defaults to Wayland. There is a new entry named "GNOME on X.org" in GDM, which when selected makes everything work as desired again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do the following since Wayland does not work correctly in many old machines:

$ sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf
Remove the comment from #WaylandEnable=false.

Save it and reboot your machine.